# PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission issue when pushed apk as system app

Tags: android, android-permissions, networkstatsmanager

I'd implemented an app to get data usage, for getting data we need to give two permissions -

- PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
- READ_PHONE_STATE

When I install app as play store app it works fine but **when I push it as system app it crashes. Reason for this crash is - PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission. For system app its default value is enabled but still it got crash & produce following exception**

java.lang.SecurityException: NetworkStats: Neither user nor current process has android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY.
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                     at android.net.INetworkStatsSession$Stub$Proxy.getHistoryIntervalForUid(INetworkStatsSession.java:425)
                                                     at android.app.usage.NetworkStats.startHistoryEnumeration(NetworkStats.java:341)
                                                     at android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(NetworkStatsManager.java:201)
                                                     at com.android.launcher3.appdatausage.DataUsageManager$2.run(DataUsageManager.java:204)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

**Once I toggle the permission it works fine.** How to resolve this?

Comment: are u using runtime permission model?

Comment: @7383 Yes, I'm using run-time permission model.